# Invalid user/usergroupd while extracting tar file

Tags: java, linux, unix, extract, tar

I am trying to extract .gz file using following command.

```
tar -xvf tezt.tar.gz
```

Extraction is successful,But userid assigned is 1003 & usergroup assigned in 200. What are these values? from where I got these?

```
[root@machine user1]# ls -l
  total 59236
  -rw------- 1 root root 60237626 Aug 27 16:47 test.tar.gz
  drwxr-xr-x 2 1003 200 4096 Feb 27 2014 folder1
  drwxr-xr-x 2 1003 200 4096 Feb 27 2014 folder2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a superuser (or if you specified `--same-owner` option), it will preserve the same ownership in the archive file.

> ```
>  --same-owner
>        try extracting files with the same ownership as exists in the ar‐
>        chive (default for superuser)
> ```

If you don't want that, use `--no-same-owner` option:

> ```
>  --no-same-owner
>        extract files as yourself (default for ordinary users)
> ```